# Android Can I append a specific record field in a URI?

Tags: android, sqlite, uri

I'm doing Android development.

My question is: can I append a specific field of a db record to a URI?

Example: suppose you have a table monuments in a SQLite DB:

```
_id INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT   
name TEXT
location TEXT
picture BLOB
```

I want now to retrieve the BLOB image of entry with ID 4 and display it; I can query the db

```
Bitmap monumentImage = null;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.my.example/monuments/4");
Cursor c = myContentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {"picture"}, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    byte[] imageBytes = c.getBlob(0);
    if (imageBytes != null) {
    monumentImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
}
ImageView myImage = findViewById(R.id.whatever);
if (monumentImage != null) {
    myImage.setImageBitmap(monumentImage);
}
```

now my question is: is there a way to append directly the record column to the uri?
as in, having something like

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.my.example/monuments/4/picture");
ImageView myImage = findViewById(R.id.whatever);
myImage.setImageURI(uri);
```

?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Just use own content provider. There you will be able to parse the URI. Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), the

> Making the Query

section.

Comment: thanks for helping.
but I think it really isn't possible to do what I want with the native setImageURI(). the android code exposed in grepcode, particularly the "resolveUri()" function, shows that a field in a db record isn't a good candidate.

Comment: It works - I just do it that way... iv_backgroundImage.setImageURI(contactPhotoUriFull);